# Pandas .sum one column only (how to?)

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have Data frame like this

```
Product     Q-ty    Price
Product A    5        10
Product B    1        3
Product B    2        3
Product A    1        10
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Product     Q-ty    Price
Product A    6        10
Product B    3        3
```

when I am trying this:

```
result = df.groupby(['Product']).sum()
```

I get this:

```
Product     Q-ty    Price
Product A    6        20
Product B    3        6
```

So it is making sum of both Q-ty and Price.
I have triend:

```
result = df.groupby(['Product','Price'])['Q-ty'].sum()
```

but it didn't work... any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by using different aggregation funcions for each column:

```
df_output = df.groupby('Product').agg({'Q-ty':'sum',  'Price':'mean'})
```

Finally you can add `df_output.reset_index()` if you do not want to work with grouped dataframes.